# difference between "tab" table and all_tables in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

what tables are returned by using (in oracle)

```
select * from tab
```

and

```
select * from all_tables
```

I would like to know the difference between two.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`tab` is an **ancient** data dictionary table that should never be used.  It exists solely to provide backwards compatibility for scripts that were written potentially decades ago.  `tab` does not get updated as new object types and new features get added.

- `all_tables` gives you information about all the tables that you have access to.
- `tab` gives you information about tables, views, and synonyms that you own (making it more similar to views like `user_tables`, `user_synonyms`, and `user_views`).  It doesn't know about things like the recycle bin, though, so `tab` will show you all the tables with names like `BIN$+K4PlriXSGetpagyHCvBGA==$0` that are in the recycle bin.  Realistically, any object types that have been added at least since the Oracle 7 days are likely to create problems for legacy data dictionary tables like `tab`.

Comment: But why is `select tname from tab where tabtype='TABLE' order by tname` (40-60ms) 3x or 4x faster than `select table_name from user_tables order by table_name` (170-190ms) in my testing (12c on Windows, using custom command line client)?

Comment: @ddevienne - I've not walked through the underlying code for the two views but I would assume that it's more costly to account for everything that has changed in the data dictionary since the Oracle 7 days than to ignore it.  Filtering out things in the recycle bin, for example, adds time but improves the results.  If you are hitting the data dictionary so often that `user_tables` isn't fast enough for you, my guess is that you are doing something wrong.