# Command difference cat Vs tab in sqlplus

Tags: oracle

I'm using sql plus. I need to know the difference between two commands.

```
SELECT * FROM cat
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM tab;
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: `cat` and `tab` must be tables, right? The first one select "everything" from the table `cat` and the second one does the same thing from table `tab`.

Comment: That one left me speechless, @Vikas.

Comment: okay, I don't know much about Oracle. Didn't know these are some existing views or something. Please pardon the silliness.

Answer (score 2):

They are both part of data dictionary and are `PUBLIC SYNONYMNS` for corresponding `SYS` tables/views.

```
SELECT object_name,
       owner,
       object_type
FROM all_objects
WHERE object_name IN (
     'CAT',
     'TAB'
);

OBJECT_NAME         OWNER             OBJECT_TYPE  
------------------- ----------------- -------------
TAB                 SYS               VIEW         
TAB                 PUBLIC            SYNONYM      
CAT                 PUBLIC            SYNONYM
```

Which are themselves `VIEWS` by the name `USER_CATALOG` and `TAB`.

```
SELECT owner,
       synonym_name,
       table_name
FROM all_synonyms
WHERE synonym_name IN (
     'TAB',
     'CAT'
);

OWNER                  SYNONYM_NAME            TABLE_NAME   
---------------------- ----------------------- -------------
PUBLIC                 CAT                     USER_CATALOG 
PUBLIC                 TAB                     TAB          
SYSTEM                 TAB                     TAB
```

If you want to see what data dictionary tables/views those `VIEW`s are selecting from, you may run

```
SELECT view_name,text_vc
FROM all_views
WHERE view_name IN ('TAB', 'USER_CATALOG');
```

**Note**: Justin Cave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14572620/7998591) says that *"tab is an ancient data dictionary table that should never be used. It exists solely to provide backwards compatibility for scripts that were written potentially decades ago."*